# Making a specific view the initial view on page load (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

This will be very easy for you Angular monsters out there. I have two views ( a list view and a grid view) each in a partial html that is injected via ng-include on a click of a button. Like this:

```
<div class = "bar">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
    <a href="#" class="list-icon" ng-class="{active: layout == 'list'}" ng-click="layout = 'list'"></a>
    <a href="#" class="grid-icon" ng-class="{active: layout == 'grid'}" ng-click="layout = 'grid'"></a>
</div>
<div ng-show="layout == 'list'" class="list">
    //ng-include for the list page is here
</div>
<div ng-show="layout == 'grid'" class="grid">
    //ng-include for the grid page is here
</div>
```

How can I initiate one of those views? grid for instance. I imagine it's done with ng-init. but I can't figure it out

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize an variable either using ng-init or in controller variable declaration:

1. ng-init="layout === 'list'"
2. $scope.layout = 'list'

Comment: Just minutes later I realized I could do this also. ng-init="layout = 'grid'" . But I like your controller-way better. I'm using yours. Thanks! I knew this would be easy.

Comment: Actually, for future visitors, you should add the ng-init way to your answer. Option1 and Option2 is a much more completed answer